# transmission replace or rebuild?

Tags: automatic-transmission

I'm new here, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I have an 06 Dodge Charger R/T and the transmission quit recently, I got a quote from edwards transmissions and engines and they are charging $3500 to rebuild it. I really can't pay that, so I'm hoping it's possible that I can have a shop just put another one in it which I can afford, but I been hearing it‘ll need reprogramming, one dealership said it's not necessary, so on these NAG1 Mercedes transmissions are they ok to just replace with one from another charger? Thanks!

Comment: You could be bolting in the same problem...

Comment: Get a second opinion. Take it to another place, don't tell them anything that the previous place said and see if you get the same answer. Get your On-board Diagnostics (OBD) codes read and interpreted as it may give you some insight.

Comment: That series of transmission was widely used on Chrysler vehicles, there's probably plenty of them around. I can't tell you about reprogramming though.